# Почему моя регулярка проверки имени и фамилии работает не так как в regexr?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

На regexr[com] я создал правило: `/^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z\-.]{2,}\s[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z\-.]{2,}$/`
Которое должно пропускать Имя и Фамилию только кириллицей с возможностью использовать дефис и точку.
Все тесты проходят на regexr под JS.
В самом js результат для, например Иванов Ив. всегда falsy. В чём различия? Как правильно обработать? И сюда же - на каком-то портале о регулярках видел, что использовать \s не оптимально, а как тогда проверить пробелы?

```js
const fullNamePattern = /^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z\-.]{2,}\s[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z\-.]{2,}$/;
console.log(fullNamePattern.test('Иванов Ив'));
```

Comment: Странно. Только что набрал в консоли `/^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z\-.]{2,}\s[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z\-.]{2,}$/.test("Иванов Ив.")`, пишет true. Может, попробуйте `.trim()`?

Comment: да, в консоли просто отрабатывает, даже более сложный вариант. трим тоже есть. я использую в составе VeeValidate

Comment: при этом, `/^([а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z-.]{2,}( [а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z-.]{2,}))$/` такой вариант тоже работает в консоли, а в наксте падает бабель

Comment: Ключи установленные при тестировании на сайте совпадают? Думаю может unicode не хватает, ключ `u`. А так же если вам нужна только кириллица, зачем у вас в выборке `a-zA-Z` присутствуют?

Comment: совпадают. вроде как надо два слеша перед . Но я сделал чуть иначе 
/(.{2,})[ ]{1}(.{2,})/ -  для проверки в общем смысле на 2 слова
/^[а-яА-ЯёЁ\- \\.]+$/ - для проверки именно символов разрешенных. мне всё равно нужно разные ошибки показывать

Comment: @sinneren Ваша регулярка работает на Иванов Ив. Вероятно ваша проблема в другой части кода, которую в вопросе вы не показываете.

Answer (score 1):

Гипотеза

Ваша страница, на которой пользователь вводит имя и фамилию в одной кодировке, а ваш файл js с регуляркой в другой.

Проверьте кодировки.